# Opening hundreds of images in Preview without having to answer "Are you sure?" each time?

Tags: macos, preview

I frequently open a folder full of images at once using Preview. I love the application dearly because it's so darn fast; I can touch the down arrow and scroll through them full size and instantly absorb "the essence" of the folder or spot that one particular, notable image I'm looking for quickly.

Note that sometimes the images are personal photos, sometimes they are experimental physics data. It doesn't matter, Preview makes this easy.

However, when I switched from my old laptop/OS to my new setup, preview now stops me in my tracks each time and asks me "Are you sure you want to open N files?"

I have looked in preferences and I can't find a setting to raise the threshold, which seems to be N=25.

**Question:** When I pen hundreds of images in Preview, is there any way I can do it without having to answer "Are you sure?" each time?

I use the "Open groups of files in the same window" option. macOS 10.15.7

[image: Are you sure?] [image: preferences]

Comment: You could just use Quicklook instead.

Comment: @nohillside I add that because experience has shown that people will complain that the images are too small and then I have to explain that I've used the [imgur resize function](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315004/303080) to show them smaller but the full, clearer images are just a click away.  I don't see how withholding that information helps the post; it was only one line of four words.

Comment: @Tetsujin No, that doesn't work nearly as well for me. If I select say 100 specific images in a folder (rather than all of them) and hit command-O I can just hold the down-arrow and it will scroll straight through those selected images in full screen. Quicklook seems to just scroll through the files in the folder (not my selection), the window is smaller, and I'm not convinced it spends about the same amount of time showing each image. It's a poor substitute.

Comment: The pictures are clearly visible, even on the iPhone.

Comment: @nohillside in my experience that doesn't always stop people from complaining :-) It's done as a courtesy.

Comment: The message doesn't show if you use `open -a Preview *` in Terminal. So you could write an Automator service for this and trigger it via the context menu in Finder.

Comment: @nohillside I have used the Automator a long time ago so I know what that is. Let me see if I understand; after I have a selection, I could configure the automator  to open the selected files all in the same window in Preview, and I could assign some hot key to that script so that I could use it any time, instead of command-O? It would work the same except the "Are you sure?" message would no longer appear?

Comment: I haven't tried, but if you use a shell script action this should work, yes.

Comment: @nohillside that's outside my current skillset; the only thing I can script is Python, the only time I open a terminal is to type `Python -i my_script.py` or `pip install package`

Comment: The script action basically consists of the command given above.

Comment: @nohillside I see, so that's a "no."